# scrollbars unresponsive when rendering web page on MS Surface touch device

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, scrollbar, touchscreen

Technology: ExtJS 5.1.1 panels and grids, MS Surface touch device, Chrome mainly.

When pages are rendered on mobile or tablet, a common behavior in browsers is to hide the scrollbars unless they are going to be used, with the mouse wheel, two fingers in a touch screen, and so on. I guess this is done to help with space saving on small screens.

We started having this issue on an MS Surface touch device, scrollbars on grids and panels do not respond and users can not scroll up or down any content, either using the touch capabilities or the mouse wheel.

We are trying to force the scrollbars to always show up and see if that helps, but we haven't had any luck with forcing them to show up.

There are no JS errors in the console.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a  [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. What you have added now doesn't give us enough information of what is going on, as there can be gazillion problems going on. So a link or example code would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue previously where Chrome scrolling would just stop when using Wikipedia. Turning off smooth scrolling in chrome://flags// fixed it for me.

I wouldn't think it's related except that you specifically mentioned Chrome as the outlier.

Here's the reddit post where I learned about it: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/8zbo48/scrolling_randomly_stops_working/